# objective c, checking if object is undefined or nil

Tags: objective-c

Ok, I created my own class(MyObject) subclassing NSObject

then in my code I declare this:

```
MyObject * myObject;
```

Then further down in my function, I do:

```
if(myObject == nil)
{
 myObject = [self getObject];
}
```

My if statement returns false, which I want it to be true.

In debug mode: just declaring it is assigning an instance to it with some random values.
So, do I have to override the init function so it returns nil, and then create my own initWith function?

Comment: Note: If your string is actually saying "undefined" it's likely you got it from a Javascript API which passes nil as literal text 'undefined', you can just use `isEqualToString:"undefined"` to check against this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Objective-C, (or C in general),

```
 MyObject* myObject;
```

inside a method implementation does **not initialize** `myObject` **with a** `nil`. Similarly,

```
 int a;
```

**does not initialize** `a` **with** 0. That's what people who made C decided long ago. There was a historical rational why this was so.

Just initialize it explicitly as

```
 MyObject* myObject=nil;
```

Note that an ivar defined in the class interface is automatically set to `zero` before `init` is called.

Update: Also note that `myObject` is a *pointer* to the real object which contains data. So, if you just do

```
 MyObject* myObject;
```

this means `myObject` points to a chunk of garbage memory, which would not correctly work at all.

```
 MyObject* myObject=nil;
```

makes `myObject` to point to **nothing**. Now it at least consistently does nothing. What this line

```
 MyObject* myObject=[[MyObject alloc] init];
```

does is to allocate a `MyObject` object in the memory, initialize it, and then make `myObject` point to the chunk of memory correctly allocated and initialized.  Now, if the `MyObject` has the interface

```
@interface MyObject:NSObject {
     NSString* string;
}
@end
```

and if you define the init method,

```
@implementation MyObject
-(id)init {
      if(self=[super init]) {
           ... do something ...
      }
      return self;
}
```

after `[super init]` is successfully performed, Objective-C guarantees that the ivar `string` is set to `nil`, i.e. `string` points to nothing. But it is not that an `NSString` is allocated or initialized.

Comment: Wait, so then there isn't a point of using alloc when instantiating...I just have to use init. Since C already allocates memory to it. That's abit messed up. Isn't it? I shouldn't have to use nil when declaring

Comment: No, C doesn't alloc the memory. See the clarification I added.

Answer (score 1):

declare MyObject to be nil:

```
MyObject *myObject = nil;
```

That way it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you initialize your myObject to nil like so:-

MyObject * myObject = nil;